# No network connectivity for my CentOS 6 installed in VMWare Fusion in MacOSX Lion

Tags: centos, linux-networking

I installed CentOS 6.2 (CentOS-6.2-x86_64-minimal.iso) with VMWare Fusion(Version 4.1.2). (Not  with EasyInstall). I am using MacOSX Lion, connect to internet via WIFI.

The centos installed does not have network connectivity. **How may I configure it to connect to wifi? **

Thanks for any help.

Below is screenshot of ifconfig:
[image]

With the setting Network Adapter, I tried both NAT and Bridged > WiFi.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you install the VMWare Tools on the CentOS guest? If not, try that and restart the VM.

A quick check to see if any device is configured would be to run `ifconfig -a`, which will show all interfaces on the system.

If an eth0 is displayed in that output, you may have an issue with interface auto-configuration. This is possibly a result of [the Network Manager service](http://www.convirture.com/ee_wiki/index.php?title=RedHat_6_Networking)... If `eth0` shows up, you have several options:

- Run `ifup eth0` to try to bring the connection online.
- Run `system-config-network` to  configure the interface.
- Configure the [interface manually](http://www.convirture.com/ee_wiki/index.php?title=RedHat_6_Networking) at `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`.

Let us know what you see, though.

Comment: What should I select for Network Adapter setting?  the 2nd screenshot in my question, which option to pick?

Comment: That doesn't matter. You're not seeing any interfaces within the guest yet.

Comment: thank you. i got it work after editing /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

Answer (score 2):

Ah.  CentOS6 doesn't connect the eth interfaces by default.

Create this file: `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`  containing these lines

```
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT="yes"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
```

...and restart your networking with 'sudo service network restart' and your eth should pull an IP via DHCP.

If you wish to set a static IP you can add IPADDR and NETMASK settings in this file, but I have not done that so experimenting with the syntax is left as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

ifconfig returns only the properly configured network interfaces.
Type

```
ifconfig -a
```

You will probably find a network interface that is not configured.
Configure it manually by editing the file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/iface-ethx

Replace ethx in the vile name by the name of the interface you found with ifconfig -a

Answer (score 1):

I tried and came to the same result.

My diagnostics : the minimal iso lacks the tools to finish a proper vmware installation. As it is, it doesn't recognize the vmware emulated hardware layer and does not install the software (perl, make, gcc) necessary to install vmware tools.

So i think we're stuck here : no network to fetch the software needed to install vmware tools and no vmware driver to get network...

Answer (score 1):

1. Install your VMWare tool.
2. Restart your machine and check if your vmtool is running. (`ps aux | grep vmware`)
3. go to the configuration `/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0`
   and comment the following lines.

> ```
>    #NM_CONTROLLED=yes
>
>    #USERCTL=no
>
>    #PEERDNS=yes
>
>    #IPV6INIT=no
> ```

4) and change `ONBOOT=yes`

5) save the file and restart the network service (service network restart) and do one final reboot.

6) `ifconfig` --> should display the `eth0` with IP address assigned.

This completely worked for me :-)